# How do I install packages in PyCharm for all projects?

Tags: python, pycharm

I use PyCharm and all the initial settings are okay.Simple package installation is working. Then why do I need to reinstall a package for each project? Is there any way to install the packages for all projects from now on?

Comment: are you using a different VE for each project?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is depending on your project settings, the project interpreter to be specific.

The project interpreter can be set to one of the following:

- an interpreter installed globally on your system
- an interpreter in a shared `virtual environment`
- an interpreter in a `virtual environment` associated with a project

Now the approach I'd recommend would be to create a shared `virtual environment` where you install your packages to, and use this environment for all your project.

That way, you have the desired result of needing to install your packages only once, but still have an environment isolated from your system environment.

To create such an environment, follow these steps:

1. Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
2. Click the cogwheel / gear icon right-side the interpreter dropdown
3. Select "Add Local..." -> Virtualenv Environment
4. Select a path as a root directory for the new environment
5. Select base interpreter you want to use
6. Tick the checkbox "Make available to all projects"
7. Click the "OK" button to save the new environment

Comment: Step 5.5. Check-on option "Inherit global site-packages", or face an implosion regarding setuptools not being installed. (Experienced with Python 3.7, pip 10.0.1 & PyCharm 2018.2.2 (Community Edition) on Windows 10, Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134)

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: I have followed the steps but "ok" button is disabled. On the environment path it is showin that "Environment Directory can be empty"

Answer (score 3):

You can download Package from the Pycharm IDE

```
1. Open Pycharm and Go to File
2. Click on Settings
3. On left Side, You will find Projects Option. Click & Expend it
4. Click on Interpreter 
5. A list of installed package will be shown
6. On Right Side, You will see a + button. Click This to install new package
7. A window will appear with Search bar, then search your package name and hit install button.
```

All steps are taken from this [**One minute Video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7CyZ0TfFaE).