# Enable "Inherit global site-packages" by default on project creation

Tags: python, pycharm

When creating a project on PyCharm, you can check "Inherit global site-packages". I do this for most projects and by default it's deselected. If I forget to select it the procedure to go back and add global packages once the project is created is a hassle.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to have this box checked by default? Maybe in a PyCharm config file somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question but doing this for all projects sounds like a bad idea. It is better to have separate `requirements.txt` files for each project/virtualenv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a PyCharm project inheriting global site-packages, after creating the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921165/make-a-pycharm-project-inheriting-global-site-packages-after-creating-the-proje)

Comment: @metatoaster thanks, I saw that. That's the process that's a hassle - mainly because it's more than zero work - haha. It would just be nice to set it by default.

Comment: @Selcuk interesting that you say so - why is that? For now at least my projects are quite small data science ones, and adding numpy, pandas, seaborn etc etc each time seems pointless when you can just use the packages in the global Python 3 install - for which I've added relevant packages with pip. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisBrowne I was stating the best practices in general. If it works for your use case more power to you. Otherwise it might introduce subtle bugs that are difficult to find when you update or remove a system-wide package, or deploy one of your projects on a different machine.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the clarification, and that's good to know for the future