# Why do I have to install all python modules again for every new project? (Pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pycharm, python-module

So I am quite new to Python and only have completed like 2 or 3 projects, but every module, like bs4, had to be installed via the IDEs terminal every time I started a new project. If I didn't do that, the IDE told me that the modules I tried to import aren't installed.

Comment: Presumably, because *you* are using a different interpreter/virtual environment for each project... which is generally considered the best practice anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select `project interpreter`.

Go to `Settings` → `Python Interpreter`. Select your environment. If you are creating a new project, use *base environment* instead of creating a "virtual environment".

**Edit**
As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, this may not be the preferred way. If you are installing dependencies, make sure you have a new conda environment (rather than using base environment) dedicated to that project. So that, if things go south, you can delete that environment and create new one.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this, almost certainly

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file with all your installed modules.

If you have pip already installed, just type in the IDE terminal:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Now you have a file with all your modules and their versions. Next time you want to install all of them with a single command, move your `requirements.txt` file to your script path and type in the terminal:

`pip install requirements.txt`

Comment: This is generally **not** the recommended approach, rather, unfortunately, dependencies should be handled "manually"... in any case, this doesn't really answer the quesition

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package via pycharm in a project, they are most likely being put into a virtual env, like a sandbox. This is so you don't get conflict with packages down the road from installing tons and tons of packages. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769641/how-do-i-install-packages-in-pycharm-for-all-projects), which i think will help you out with what your trying to avoid with reinstalling packages over and over.